# Not able to pass concatenated value to an array

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Folks,

I am trying to create a new Array Elements which is concatenation of two variables.

```
foreach($prodarray as $key => $value) 
{
    $prodarray2[$key] = $q_words.' '.$value;
}
```

Above code is not creating `$prodarray2`.

But if I remove `$q_words` and just keep `$value`, it creates the array.

Why is it so?

Can someone please help me with this, please?

Cheers
Natasha Thomas

Comment: What's the output of var_dump($q_words)?

Comment: can you please add an example of the data, and maybe the surrounding code so we can help you better?

Comment: Is the $q_words defined? I have tried it by making sure everything is defined and tested it and it worked just fine. So as BigFatBaby and kevmo314 have noted to better help you please post all the surrounding code.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely answer is that `$q_words` is not a scalar value (ie it's an array or object or undefined, rather than being a string or number).  I suggest that you crank up your error reporting, then you'll probably get an error that will tell you why your array is not being created.  See the [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) man page for details.

Your could also run `var_dump` on `$q_words` before you concatentate it to find out what it's current value is.  And if you install the [XDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/) PHP extension both errors and var_dump output will be easier to read and more informative.